# Is it possible to profile standalone react-native app inside android-studio?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, expo

My production app is crashing on a certain device. But my app is built using expo so unable to open my app project inside android studio. I do profiling in react-devtools profiler but it only shows component render time and not so memory consuming, so i want to profile my standalone app in android-studio for finding memory leak.

Comment: as far as I know, this looks unlikely since Studio must profile by measuring execution times of java classes, but what you are looking for is profiling of JavaScript code.

Comment: app is crashing in some devices like Android g9 pro but i haven't those devices, then how to debug those crashing ?